# Tensor Contraction producing a trace.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, tensors, linear-transformations

I was reading a meta-paper and came across this notation.

Given $V$ as a vector space, then there exists a dual space $V^*$. $V^*\otimes V$ is isomorphic to the set of linear transformation that map $V$ into $V$, which is the set of $n$ by $n$ matrices with entries in the scalar field, where $n$ is the dimension of $V$. Then there is a mapping from $V^*\otimes V$ into a scalar field which takes a decomposable element $f\otimes v$ to $f(v)$. This is the mapping that sends a matrix to the trace of that matrix.

I think I've found my answer in this article: [The Duality Functor in Linear Algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159499/the-duality-functor-in-linear-algebra)

So, this is a tensor contraction. How, in this case, does this tensor contraction produce a trace? I am not sure about that. Good books on tensors might be helpful since I'm having trouble with this. Thanks.

Comment: Note that $V^*\otimes V$ is only isomorphic to the space of linear transformations $V\to V$ if $V$ is finite-dimensional.

Comment: Noted. Thanks. The author didn't mention whether V was finite-dimensional. It is a meta-paper about his work, not the work itself. (He's applying this idea from linear algebra to tensor products of locally free groups, and I got somewhat lost.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $V$ is $n$-dimensional, then let $\mathbf e_1, \mathbf e_2, \ldots, \mathbf e_n$ be a basis for $V$, and let $\pi_1,\pi_2,\ldots,\pi_n$ be a basis for $V^*$, defined by
$$\pi_i(\mathbf e_j) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if }i=j \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

$V^*\otimes V$ has a basis consisting of all elements of the form $\pi_i\otimes \mathbf e_j$, so every element of $V^*\otimes V$ is a linear combination of such things. The way it can be interpreted as a linear mapping is by the rule
$$ (\pi_i\otimes \mathbf e_j)(v) = (\pi_i(v))\mathbf e_j $$
and extend to the full $V^*\otimes V$ by linearity.

The matrix corresponding to $F\in V^*\otimes V$ this mapping is the one whose element at position $j,i$ is the coefficient of $\pi_i\otimes \mathbf e_j$ when $F$ is written in this basis. In other words, $\pi_i\otimes \mathbf e_j$ corresponds to a matrix with $1$ at index $j,i$ and zeroes everywhere else, and these matrices combine linearly.

Now *contraction* in $V^*\otimes V$ is defined by the rule $v^*\otimes v \mapsto v^*(v)$, which means that its effect on basis elements is
$$ \pi_i\otimes\mathbf e_j \mapsto \pi_i(\mathbf e_j) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{if }i=j \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$

So when we write some $F\in V^*\otimes V$ as a linear combination of $(\pi_i\otimes \mathbf e_j)$s, all of the ones with $i\ne j$ drop out when we contract, and the coefficients of $\pi_i\otimes \mathbf e_i$ are all just *added*. But these coefficients are just the elements on position $i,i$ in the matrix representation, and their sum is the trace of the matrix!

Comment: Ah ha. Oh, so it's the tensor contraction V*⊗V that is like, I'm not sure how to say this properly. using a (diagonal) basis. So, the coefficients are then added together as part of the contraction?  You mean the coefficients are just the elements in the i=j position in the matrix representation?. And of course the sum is the trace of the matrix. Ah, that's the part I was missing how we got the the tensor contraction in V∗⊗V act like a (diagonal) basis. (That's not quite the right term.)

Comment: Thanks. Your explanation was so clear and my restating was so awkward, that I wanted to give it another try to do justice to your explanation. (I haven't felt this dense since grad school.) Here goes: You're applying a basis that basically puts zeros everywhere except the diagonal, that is, where i=j. So when the tensor multiplication is applied, only the diagonal has values other than 0. (Unless zeros were there to begin with.) Then tensor contraction drops out all the zeros and the diagonal is summed, producing the trace. This is akin to creating a determinant. Right?

Comment: @MarkLaPolla: Note that I had a horrible typo in my last equation, fixed now. I don't think "applying a basis that basically puts zeros everywhere except the diagonal" is an entirely correct way of saying it; I would prefer: Contraction is a _linear mapping_ that ignores basis elements outside the diagonal.

Comment: Noted and thanks. Much better. Yes. I like your way of putting it. Thanks again. It's very clear now. I finished the reading the paper. This was very helpful. I am, for now, out of the woods. I appreciate the help.